# ComboBox Items not refresed after reseting DataSource

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a couple of ComboBoxes on a Win Form that I always set list to the DataSource like this:

```
aComboBox.DataSource = someList;
foreach(Object obj in aComboBox.Items) {
  // do something
}
```

This works perfectly fine for me, however, I have some trouble when trying to reset the data like this:

```
aComboBox.DataSource = null;
aComboBox.DataSource = someOtherList;
foreach(Object obj in aComboBox.Items) {
  // do something else
}
```

The DataSource is reset successfully, but that does not trigger to reset the Items. I tried to call `aComboBox.Items.Clear()` to clean up the Items, no resetting happened.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Hmm, sounds strange. Could you please add the declaration of those two lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is all because of the form is "owned" by another form, where I have it `child.Show(this)` in the parent form to have the convenient to access methods from the parent form in the child.

In addition, using the BindingSource to look after the data binding will do the trick. This is what I've done:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource;
aComboBox.DataSource = bs;
bs.DataSource = someList;
//
// after some processing
//
bs.DataSource = null;
bs.DataSource = someOtherList;
```

Comment: I had the same issue and spent 2 hours trying to solve it before seeing this answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try steps in this sequence

```
cmbBox.Items.Clear();
cmbBox.DataSource = SomeOtherList;
cmbBox.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't see a System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.DataBind()